# Calendar_date_select gem for Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-timepicker

I want both date and time to select in rails 3 application the  **`"Calendar_date_select"`** is not working in rails 3.
 can any one tell any jquery or gem which work on rails 3 to select both date and time

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I prefer http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ to select date in different formats

Comment: but i want both date and time